# Validaterror when installing two modules

Tags: tags, odoo

I want to add two other modules in my application. but when I try to install the modules Waherouse and purchase management, installation is not possible with this error
"
***ValidateError
Une erreur est apparue lors de la validation du/des champ(s) vat: Ce code de TVA ne semble pas correct. Note: le format attendu est 'CC##' (CC=Country Code, ##=VAT Number)***
"

The accounting module is already installed and the completed status

I need your help

Thank

Comment: seems the vat number of anything/-body (maybe the company) is wrong. can you switch the language under user settings to english and paste us the english error message? :-)

Comment: Check the VAT number you entered when created the company. Should be something like FR123456789.